# How do I run unit tests in package directory

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a python code base where I have refactored a module (file) into a package (directory) as the file was getting a bit large and unmanageable. However, I cannot get my unit tests running as desired with the new structure.

I place my unit test files directly alongside the code it tests (this is a requirement and cannot change - no separate `test` directories):

```
app/
+-- app.py
+-- config.py
+-- config_test.py
+-- model/
|   +-- __init__.py
|   +-- base.py
|   +-- base_test.py
|   +-- square.py
|   +-- square_test.py
+-- test.py
+-- web.py
+-- web_test.py
```

Previously, the `model` package was the `model.py` module with a `model_test.py` test suite.

There is a top-level test runner - `test.py` and that works fine. It finds the test cases inside the `model` directory and runs them successfully (it uses the `discovery` feature of `unittest` - see end of post for `test.py`):

```
$ python test.py
```

However, I also want to be able to directly run the test cases in the `model` directory:

```
$ python model/base_test.py
```

This does not work, because the test is inside the package directory. The imports in the code fail because they are either not in a module when imported directly by the test suite or the search path is wrong.

For instance, in `model/square.py`, I can import `base.py` in one of two ways:

```
from model import Base
```

or

```
from .base import Base
```

These both work fine when `model` is imported. But when inside the `model` test suites, I cannot import `square` because `square` cannot import `base`.

`square_test.py` contains imports like:

```
import unittest
from square import Square
... test cases ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

For the first type of import in `square.py` (`from model import Base`), I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

Fair enough, `sys.path` has `/home/camh/app/model` and there is no `model` module in there.

For the second type of import in `square.py` (`from .base import Base`), I get the error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I cannot figure out how to do my imports that allows me to have tests alongside the unit-under-test and be directly runnable. I want directly runnable test suites as often I do not want to run the entire set of tests, but just target individual tests:

```
$ python model/square_test.py SquareTest.test_equal_sides
```

I cannot do that with my test runner because it just uses discovery to run all the tests and discovery is not compatible with specifying individual test suites or test functions.

My test runner (`test.py`) is just:

```
import os, sys
sys.argv += ['discover', os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), '*_test.py']
unittest.main(module=None)
```

Comment: I only used `nosetests -vw .` in `app`, what is the benefit of keeping a separate `test.py` when nose would do it for you?

Comment: or specific test with `nosetests -vv model/square_test.py`

Comment: @Gang I am not using `nose`. `test.py` is needed because I need to modify the standard discover pattern to `*_test.py`. I would prefer to stick with the standard python unit test module and not use a separate testing framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can invoke the `unittest` module from the command line with arguments:

```
python -m unittest model.square_test
```

If you are using python3 you can use file names too:

```
python3 -m unittest model/square_test.py
```

Comment: Can I use the python3 form and run specific tests? I can do `python -m unittest model.square_test.SquareTest.test_equal_sides`, but I can't make it work with the filename. It gets a bit cumbersome if I want to run multiple individual tests using the first form.

Answer (score 0):

suggestions:

add `app/__init__.py`, and treat `app` as package instead of `model`

one way is for all tests, using explicit `from app.model.square import Square`

The relative import should be fine, as long as using `nosetests -vw .` in `app/` directory.

These all under the price of removing `app/test.py`

Another common mistake after re-factoring, is the `.pyc` not all removed and re-generated.